# Can you identify these 20 year old LEGO sets? Castle pieces with red bird and tall staircase?

Tags: set-identification

We have boxes of LEGO which our children used to play with but now the grandchildren want to build things. Can anyone recognize which sets we might have so we can look up the instructions?

[image]

Answer (score 14):

It looks like the bulk of the parts are from [The Chamber of Secrets (4730)](https://brickset.com/sets/4730-1/The-Chamber-of-Secrets):

[image: 4730]

As Henrik mentioned, [Sorting Hat (4701)](https://brickset.com/sets/4701-1/Sorting-Hat) is also present:

[image: 4701]

Jason pointed out that [Dumbledore's Office (4739)](https://brickset.com/sets/4729-1/Dumbledore-s-Office) is also present:

[image: 4739]

I thought it might be worth noting that these old Harry Potter sets are fairly valuable to collectors. The Chamber of Secrets alone in complete used condition is currently worth ~$100 USD.

Comment: There's also definitely some pieces from [Dumbledore's Office](https://brickset.com/sets/4729-1/Dumbledore-s-Office); note the swirly thingy, and the quarter-cylinder pieces. And that pagoda roof piece is from still a different Harry Potter set, but I'm not sure which

Comment: @JasonBaker Where can I find those prices? I might have to raid my parents cellar.

Comment: Ah, I assume from following those links.

Comment: Wow. “20-year-old” sounds like “ancient”, but _Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets_ was published in 1998, indeed nearly 20 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

That yellow round tile is from [4701 - Sorting Hat](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=4701-1). There are other parts that make me think there's probably more Harry Potter, but none that I can quickly identify a set from.